# On using "time span"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Is this usage correct:

> The short time span between the first and second experiment ...

I am using it as a synonym for (period or gap). Is this correct usage?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be correct?

Comment: @ColleenV I have not used it before to be honest.

Comment: If you are confused about whether `time span` is one word or two words, you will find this useful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74873/is-it-timespan-or-time-span.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular problem with that usage. A brief search finds similar sentences:

> Next he addresses the short time span between the origin autographs and their copies...

Answer (score -1):

### Your usage of *time span* is correct, but there is another issue

---

I will add that, *technically*, you should say "experiments" (plural) because experiments is referring to both the first and second experiment:

> The short time span between the first and second experiments ...

That said, as you have it now, a reader/listener probably wouldn't bat an eye at the error because it is commonly made in day to day speech.

You might also say:

> The short time span between the first experiment and the second ...

Comment: Not it's not necessary to make "experiments" plural. For example, [These differences between the first and second experiment are described in the following paragraphs.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3363397/). If it was written without "the first" and "the second" we would need the plural, e.g. "The short time span between experiments..."

Comment: @ coll I was taught that you use the plural verb when you use "and" because both nouns are treated together as a multiple ("they are the first and second experiments") but the singular form of the verb is to be used with all other conjunctions because they are compared as singular nouns ("neither the first experiment nor the second *is*").

Comment: “Both the first and the second experiment are conclusive.” We can use “are” without making “experiment” plural because of the conjunction. I know this more intuitively than by a rule, so I will have to do some research or find someone else to explain it.